# Open mha image files in Python (2015 brats challenge dataset)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use deep learning for medical image segmentation as my graduation thesis, the data used is 2015 brats challenge.

for example:
[MHA file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHgZn.png)

but i don't how to open the .mha files by use python.I use the tensorflow framework, so it's more convenient to use python, and besides that, I need to do some preprocessing of the data graph.

```
from medpy.io import load
url = r'G:\path\to\mine.mha'
mage_data,image_header = load(url)
```

Then:

```
medpy.core.exceptions.DependencyError: Loading images of type Itk/Vtk MetaImage (.mhd, .mha/.raw) requires a third-party module that could not be encountered. Reason: No module named 'filter'.
```

---

The brats challenge is an international competition.But I don't know what network structure I'm supposed to use to train my network. If you have good advice, please let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [MedPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MedPy) package for this.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-numpy python-scipy libboost-python-dev build-essential
```

Then:

```
sudo pip install nibabel pydicom medpy
```

And the Python usage:

```
from medpy.io import load
mage_data, image_header = load('/path/to/image.mha')
```

The library supports some useful preprocessing and analysis functions as well.

Good luck!

Comment: ,sorry,It seems that there have been some mistakes.